# Unbounded set in $V[G]$ has an unbounded subset in $V$?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Suppose $\kappa$ is a cardinal preserved in the generic extension $V[G]$. Let $Y \subseteq \kappa$ be an unbounded set in $V[G]$. Does there always exist an $X \in V$ such that $X \subseteq Y$ and $X$ is unbounded?

This question comes from Section 18 of James Cummings' [*Singular Cardinal Arithmetic*](https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlId=10.1305%2Fndjfl%2F1125409326). In this context, he forced with the Levy collapses $\operatorname{Col}(\omega,\delta^{+\omega}) \times \operatorname{Col}(\delta^{+\omega+2},<\kappa)$, and fixed "$X \subseteq \gamma$ unbounded of order type $\delta_V^{+\omega+1}$...". In the next line, he then says that "However, it is easy to see that there is $Y \in V$ with $Y \subseteq X$ unbounded".

This observation is certainly not easy for me, so my questions are:

1. Why do such a $Y$ exist?
2. Is the existence of such a $Y$ limited to forcing with Levy collapse?

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**: Fixed the broken link.

**EDIT 2**: I re-asked the question on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402333/unbounded-set-in-vg-has-an-unbounded-subset-in-v/402337#402337), and have accepted an answer.

Comment: It's certainly not true in general that such an $X$ need exist (what if $cf^{V[G]}(\kappa)<cf^V(\kappa)$?).

Comment: Why is the link going to Google and not the actual text (DOI are there for a reason)? Also, what's $\gamma$?

Comment: Another example, at a lower level than the one given by @NoahSchweber: A Mathias real is an unbounded subset of $\omega$ with no unbounded subset in the ground model.

Comment: @AndreasBlass ... I somehow stuck an "uncountable" in there. That's a much better example!

Comment: Hi all, apologies as I've included the wrong link. I've updated it.